# What companion plants will help the growth of young pines?

Tags: plant-recommendations, pines, companion-planting

I recently planted a 2m (6.5ft) high relatively young [Pinus pinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_pine) in zone 8a (−12.2 °C, 10 °F). It is going well so far. I tried to find out what plants I should grow in its vicinity that would help the pine be stronger and healthier. I searched the internet, and there is a lot of information on plants that *thrive* under pines, but not on plants that *help* pines.

Are there any such plants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article from [Trees for Life](https://treesforlife.org.uk/forest/symbiosis/) talks about Scotts pine and chanterelle mushrooms being symbiotic, perhaps you can get something tasty from your pines as well!

Mycroryzal nets can mesh with an entire forest work of plants, [even sharing carbon between different tree species](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2084488-trees-share-vital-goodies-through-a-secret-underground-network/).